# python filter and list and apply "filtered indices" to another list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Elegant and efficient ways to mask a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274774/python-elegant-and-efficient-ways-to-mask-a-list)

I have two equal sized lists, something like:

```
a=["alpha","beta","kappa","gamma","lambda"]
b=[1,2,None,3,4,5]
```

What I would like to do is identify and delete the none element in list [b] and then remove the corresponding element in list [a]. Here, for example, I would like to delete none and "kappa".

I am aware of:

filter(bool,b)

which would remove the None elements from [b], but, how do I go about deleting the corresponding entry in list[a]?

I tried zip, something like (the idea was to pack and unpack):

```
a=["a","b","c","d","e"]
b=[1,2,None,3,4]
c=zip(a,b)
d=filter(bool,c)
```

..but this does not work. [d] still has the none elements.

I would appreciate any pythonic way to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done neatly with [`itertools.compress()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) and a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
>>> a=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> b=[1, 2, None, 3, 4]
>>> selectors = [x is not None for x in b]
>>> list(itertools.compress(a, selectors))
['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
>>> list(itertools.compress(b, selectors))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This method means you only generate the selectors once (and `itertools.compress()` should be nice and fast).

Comment: Actually, this answer does look more elegant - in that, the selector is generated only once and then reused twice.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = [a[i] for i,v in enumerate(a) if b[i] is not None]
b = [x for x in b if x is not None]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Very pythonic. So, now I use a=[a[i] for i,v in enumerate(a) if b[i] is not None] and b=filter(bool,b) which seems to yield the right result.

Comment: Great! This is a basic solution, make sure you take the time to learn the tools mentioned in the other answers too, they are very powerful.

Comment: @JamesW Note that ``filter(bool, b)`` will also remove any elements that evaluate to ``False`` - in your case, ``0``, for example. As such, you are much better off with ``[x for x in b if x is not None]`` (which is also more readable), unless that is definitely the behavior your want.

Comment: @Aesthete, Thanks again. I have another question: So, for [a] I use what you have suggested. But, for [b] I prefer to use the filter method. Do you think I should be using the filter method or the for loop as you have suggested: "b = [x for x in b if x is not None]"?

Comment: @Lattyware, what you have said makes sense. How about if I use filter(None,b) - I think this is the same as [x for x in b if x is not None] right?

Comment: @JamesW Yes, that's a perfectly good equivalent. (Except note that in 3.x it is equivalent to a generator expression, not a list comprehension). That said, I do recommend you check my answer - ``itertools.compress()`` does what this code does, but does it in C - which will be faster. No point reinventing the wheel when there is a great one sat right there.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a list comprehension and add that condition to the generator expression:

```
>>> a=["a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> b=[1,2,None,3,4]

>>> [x for x in zip(a,b) if x[1] is not None]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4)]

>>> [x for x,m in zip(a,b) if m is not None]
['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: I would argue it'd be nicer to unpack the tuple, rather than index on it.