# 1d list indexing python: enhance MaskableList

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy, indexing

A common problem of mine is the following:

As input I have (`n` is some int `>1`)

```
W = numpy.array(...)
L = list(...)
```

where

```
len(W) == n
>> true
shape(L)[0] == n
>> true
```

And I want to sort the list `L` regarding the values of `W` and a comparator. My idea was to do the following:

```
def my_zip_sort(W,L):
    srt = argsort(W)
    return zip(L[srt],W[srt])
```

This should work like this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = zeros(4)
b[0]=3;b[1]=2;b[2]=[1];b[3]=4
my_zip_sort(a,b)
>> [(c,1)(b,2)(a,3)(d,4)]
```

But this does not, because

```
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

thus, I need to do another loop:

```
def my_zip_sort(W,L):
    srt = argsort(W)
    res = list()
    for i in L:
        res.append((L[srt[i]],W[srt[i]]))
    return res
```

I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274774/python-elegant-and-efficient-ways-to-mask-a-list/10274990) about a `MaskableList`, but this does not work for me (as you can read in the comments), because I would not only need to hold or discard particular values of my list, but also need to re-order them:

```
a.__class__
>> msk.MaskableList
srt = argsort(b)
a[srt]
>> ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

### Concluding:

I want to find a way to sort a `list` of objects by constraints in an `array`. I found a way myself, which is kind of nice except for the list-indexing. Can you help me to write a class that works likewise to `MaskableList` for this task, which has a good performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to extend `list` do avoid the `for`-loop. A `list-comprehension` is sufficient and probably the best you can do here, if you expect a new `list` of `tuples`:

```
def my_zip_sort(W, L):
    srt = argsort(W)
    return [(L[i], W[i]) for i in srt]
```

Example:

```
n = 5
W = np.random.randint(10,size=5)
L = [chr(ord('A') + i) for i in W]

L # => ['A', 'C', 'H', 'G', 'C']

srt = np.argsort(W)
result = [(L[i], W[i]) for i in srt]


print result
[('A', 0), ('C', 2), ('C', 2), ('G', 6), ('H', 7)]
```

Comment: That is great! I just built `class MultiIndexList(list):   def __getitem__(self,indices):   try: return list(self)[indices]   except(TypeError): return [self[i] for i in indices]`