# How to show name of predicted classes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Predict returns me a numpy array (which consists only from 0 and 1) for every column.

How to print names of columns which have 1 and dont show columns which have 0?

```
predict

[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

I have list of columns names - `columns_names`:

['1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '2', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '3', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

```
type(predict) - numpy.ndarray

type(columns_names) - list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas dataframes to help with labelling your numpy matrix.

```
import pandas as pd

predict = [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]

columns_names = ['1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '2', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '3', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

df = pd.DataFrame(predict, columns=columns_names)
df.columns[df.any()].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['15', '17', '24', '6']
```

You can use,

```
df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x.eq(1)].tolist(), axis=1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['17', '24'], ['6'], ['15', '24']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One additional question:How to return it in format of numpy array? e.g. [['15', '17'], ['24'], ['6']]

Comment: @GennadyMandarinov See Update

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple list comprehension without the need to import any external modules.

```
list(i for i,j in zip(columns_names, predict) if j)
```

This is a concept known as "masking." You can read more about it at this post: [Python: Elegant and efficient ways to mask a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274774/python-elegant-and-efficient-ways-to-mask-a-list)